# Swapping lines in a matrix to get an upper triangular matrix without zeros

Tags: c, matrix, while-loop, line

I am trying to calculate the determinant of a given matrix through the use of multiplying the numbers on a diagonal. I already have the code to put it into the upper triangular matrix configuration but sometimes the given matrix has a zero on the diagonal that could be simply moved with the whole row and solve the issue. That's the part of the code I am having trouble with. Do any of you have an idea how I could solve it?

This is the code I have tried. The operation itself should be happening in the while cycle but it doesn't seem to work. I am at a loss.

This is a matrix I tried and it didn't work:

```
 4   7  -2   3   8
 2  -4   5   3   0
 9  -6   4   5  -2
 4   8   3   0   1
-8   4   6   5   2
```

(it has to be saved as a .txt file and written into the code with the extension)

the output is the same as the input but it should have switched the last 2 rows and it didn't.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h> 
#define MAX 100

int main() 
{
    FILE *fr;
    int i,j,k,m=0,q=0,count=1;
    double cache;
    double ratio, det = 1;
    int n = 0;
    char c;
    char subor[MAX];

    printf("Input the name of your file: ");
    scanf("%s", subor); 

    fr = fopen(subor,"r");

    if (fr == NULL)
    {
    printf("Unable to open file: %s", subor);
    return 0;
    }

    for (c = getc(fr); c != EOF; c = getc(fr))
    if (c == '\n')
            n = n + 1;

    fclose(fr);
    printf("\nDimensions of the given matrix: %dx%d\n\n", subor, n, n);

    fr =fopen(subor,"r");
    
    float a[n][n];

    printf("Matrix:\n");

    for(i=0;i< n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j< n;j++)
        {
            fscanf(fr, "%g%*c",&a[i][j]);
            printf("%g\t",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fr);

    while(a[m][m] == 0.0 && m != n)
    {
    q=m;
    while(a[m][m] == 0.0 && q != n)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                cache=a[m][i];
            a[m][i]=a[q+1][i];
            a[q+1][i]=cache;
            count = count*(-1);
        }
    ++q;
    }
    ++m;
    }

    printf("\nEdited: \n");

    for(i=0;i< n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j< n;j++)
        {
            printf("%g\t",a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you execute

```
while(a[m][m] == 0.0 && m != n)
```

the value of `m` is `0` and the value of `a[0][0]` is `4` so the loop terminates. In other words, all the code inside the `while` never executes. And you never reach the code that swaps the rows.

Most likely you wanted a `for` loop with a traditional index counter.

Comment: I didn't think of that.  So if I switched the first `while` loop for: ```for(m=0;m<n;m++)```? and getting rid of the `++m;` at the end